# Capture Keystrokes

Tags: c#

I need to capture keystokes from a wedge device and prevent any controls or the form from receiving them. I also need to be able to know the value (char). I have tried overriding the ProcessCmdKey(Keys) and ProcessDialogChar(char) events. In the ProcessCmd event I can suppress the keystroke if it's one I want, but I the character isn't a parameter of the event. In the ProcessDialogChar event the character is there, but I cannot prevent the form or control with the focus from receiving the key. Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was not how I wanted to do it, but because I needed to fix this and move on I put a hidden textbox on the form and as soon as I see the character that signals the possible start of the string of data I want to capture I set focus to that text box and respond to the TextChanged event. If I haven't seen the ending character before I timer expires I clear the textbox and start again. Kludge, but it works and got me to the next task.

Answer (score 5):

You'll want to add this during Form load:

```
Application.AddMessageFilter(this);
```

Add this constant:

```
private const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;
```

And this method:

```
public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
{
    Keys keyCode = (Keys)(int)m.WParam & Keys.KeyCode;
    bool retVal = false;

    if (m.Msg == WM_KEYDOWN)
    {
        // Handle the keypress
        retVal = true;
    }

    return retVal;
}
```

By returning true, your form and control(s) will never see the key press.

Comment: Couple of notes for things I didn't make clear: You need to implement IMessageFilter, which has one method, PreFilterMessage. You actually don't have to implement this on your form, you can create an entirely separate object if you want that implements this interface. Although I'm not sure, you should be able to call AddMessageFilter before your form is created, since the message filter belongs to your GUI thread's message pump.

Comment: Thanks, I've done that and it works, but I'm still in the same predicament I was with overriding ProcessCmdKey. I don't have the actual character being entered. For instance on my keyboard the character '^' is keyCode D6. I assume the Shift key can be teased out of one of the parameters. I am trying to avoid translating to characters myself.